# jQuery Range Slider with fixed values and associated text output

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I´m new here.. sorry for my bad English :D

I´m looking for a range slider with fixed values and additional text output.

Here is a example: http://james2013.batcave.net/s100.htm

```
<p>
</p><div id="resolution-slider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
<div id="resolution"></div>
<div class="resolution-preview">6</div>

<h4>Slider width is set in css for this page</h4>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var valMap = [6, 10, 12, 18 , 35, 56];
    $("#resolution-slider").slider({
      value: valMap[0],  // Start slider from first (0th) element
      max: valMap.length-1, // Set "max" attribute to array length minus 1
      min: 0,
      values: [0], 
      create: function( event, ui ) {  // Place numeric value on page before slide
      $(".resolution-preview").html(valMap[0]); 
      },
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#resolution").val(valMap[ui.values[0]]); // Fetch selected value from array               
        $(".resolution-preview").html(valMap[ui.values[0]]);
      }  
    });
});
</script>
```

If the number 18 is displayed, a text that applies only to this value must also be displayed.

If a different number is selected, a different text will appear.

Thanks for the help guys <3

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you done any research, for example into javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, always provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Additionally, it's good to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Unfortunately I have little knowledge of javascript. I used to be able to, but I haven't worked in IT for over 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using a Range, you do not need to use `values` only the 1 `value`. Consider the following example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var valMap = ["6 (Six)", "10 (Ten)", "12 (Twelve)", "18 (Eighteen)", "35 (Thirty Five)", "56 (Fifty Six)"];
  $("#resolution-slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    max: valMap.length - 1,
    min: 0,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $(".resolution-preview").html(valMap[0]);
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".resolution-preview").html(valMap[ui.value]);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#resolution-slider {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.resolution-preview {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p></p>

<div id="resolution-slider"></div>
<div class="resolution-preview">6</div>

<h4>Slider width is set in css for this page</h4>
```

As the slider is moved from `0` to `5`, that value is then used as the Index of the `valMap` array.

**Updated**

If you want to display text, you simply need to update the Array so it has text instead of just Numbers.

Comment: @ThomasDee what text do you want to display. I do not see any "text" in your example.

Comment: Thats the problem :D I don`t know how to do it.

Comment: @ThomasDee You need to clarify what you want show. Do you want `6` or `six`? Or some other details?

Comment: I want it both. `6` AND `six` :)